# Python - how to split list for creating new column? pandas

Tags: python, pandas, list, split

I have a data frame like this

```
    col1    col2 
    [A, B]   1
    [A, C]   2
```

I would like to separate col1 into two columns and the output, I would like it out in this form

```
col1_A  col1_B  col2
  A       B       1
  A       C       2
```

I have tried this `df['col1'].str.rsplit(',',n=2, expand=True)`
but it showed `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`

Comment: df[['col_A','col_b']]=pd.DataFrame(df['col1'].tolist())

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) + [`pop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html)

```
df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(df.pop('col1').values.tolist(),
                          columns=['col1_A', 'col1_B']))

print(df)

   col2 col1_A col1_B
0     1      A      B
1     2      A      C
```

It's good practice to try and avoid `pd.Series.apply`, which often amounts a Python-level loop with an additional overhead.

Comment: @AntonvBR, I haven't look at the source but test it.. `%timeit df['col1'].tolist()` vs `%timeit df['col1'].values.tolist()`. In general, (I feel) the Pandas API seems to add non-O(1) overheads to simple methods :S

Comment: @AntonvBR, What worries me is that it's not a *fixed factor* slower. It's something O(*n*). Really the Pandas method should be able to short-circuit straight to the NumPy method when applicable.

Comment: Maybe by setting some global setting to the dataframe class? or decorate it

Comment: Ok I'm looking at the source now and yes. it is the datetime control it does. It is the difference between: `pd.Series([pd.Timestamp('2018'), pd.Timestamp('2019')]).values.tolist(), pd.Series([pd.Timestamp('2018'), pd.Timestamp('2019')]).tolist()`. And from what I can see the series values are sent to the function instead of a dtype control. To handle mixed types? Source: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/0409521665bd436a10aea7e06336066bf07ff057/pandas/core/base.py#L893-L910

Comment: Sorry for posting a lot here.... Ok so the function check if it is datetimelike: so this function https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/0409521665bd436a10aea7e06336066bf07ff057/pandas/core/dtypes/common.py#L647 with multiple or tests.... Why can't it simply make a simple dtype check instead of this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "col1": [['A', 'B'], ['A', 'C']],
    "col2": [1, 2],
})
df['col1_A'] = df['col1'].apply(lambda x: x[0])
df['col1_B'] = df['col1'].apply(lambda x: x[1])
del df['col1']
df = df[df.columns[[1,2,0]]]
print(df)

  col1_A col1_B  col2
0      A      B     1
1      A      C     2
```

Comment: df['col1'].str[0]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
>> df_expanded = df['col1'].apply(pd.Series).rename(
     columns = lambda x : 'col1_' + str(x))

>> df_expanded

  col1_0 col1_1
0      A      B
1      A      C
```

Adding these columns to the original dataframe:

```
>> pd.concat([df_expanded, df], axis=1).drop('col1', axis=1)

  col1_0 col1_1  col2
0      A      B     1
1      A      C     2
```

If columns need to be named as the first element in the rows:

```
df_expanded.columns =  ['col1_' + value
                        for value in df_expanded.iloc[0,:].values.tolist()]

  col1_A col1_B
0      A      B
1      A      C
```

Comment: There is an add prefix function to the dataframe class.

Comment: well, the important things is that it can be done applying `pandas.Series` to the column

Answer (score 0):

Zip values and column name and use insert to get right position.

```
for ind,(k,v) in enumerate(zip(zip(*df.pop('col1').tolist()),['col1_A', 'col1_B'])):
    df.insert(ind, v, k)
```

---

**Full example**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "col1": [['A', 'B'], ['A', 'C']],
    "col2": [1, 2],
})

for ind,(k,v) in enumerate(zip(zip(*df.pop('col1').tolist()),['col1_A', 'col1_B'])):
    df.insert(ind, v, k)

print(df)
```

Returns:

```
  col1_A col1_B  col2
0      A      B     1
1      A      C     2
```